# cannot execute binary file - CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, canopy

I am running a virtual CentOS environment using virtual box. I am trying to install and run enthought canopy. But after installation canopy won't run. I simply get

```
 ./canopy: line3:/home/Andrew/Canopy/bin/_python: cannot execute binary file
 ./canopy: line3:/home/Andrew/Canopy/bin/_python: Success
```

But nothing happens. a GUI should open up.

I am wondering what is causing this error.

It is basically a fresh install of operating system. Only other thing I have done is installed python 2.7.  Also I am a novice at using linux-style OS. so I may be missing something very basic

Comment: What architecture is your system? What architecture is that binary? Were did you get canopy from? Did you get the right version for your architecture?

Comment: Please show your terminal transcript including a `pwd` command and its output. Also show the contents of your environment variables (`env` command and its output.)